# Getting "can't find symbol" error in cmd line when compile file with main method, but runs OK in IDE

Tags: java, compiler-errors

This is just a very simple test of compiling a few Java files in the same package (one has main method and others have methods that are called by it).

TransportBike.java and TransportCar.java have 1 method each.

```java
package multFileCompile;

public class TransportBike {
    public void wheels() {
        System.out.println("A bike has two wheels.");
    }
}
```

```java
package multFileCompile;

public class TransportCar {
    public void wheels() {
        System.out.println("A car has four wheels.");
    }   
}
```

There is one file with main method that calls both their methods. it runs fine when inside Eclipse. No errors.

```java
package multFileCompile;

public class TransportationDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TransportBike harley = new TransportBike();
        TransportCar mustang = new TransportCar();
        
        harley.wheels();
        mustang.wheels();
    }
}
```

When I compile the bike and car files from commandline, they compile and .class created. When I try to compile the TransportDriver.java file, I get an "Can't find symbol" error on both lines where the new objects are created. I tried using extends in the car and bike files thinking it was access issue, but these are in same package and public. That did not work in any case. I checked syntax and can not find out why this file won't compile.

Comment: Can you show the command you are using from the command line?

Comment: My gut feeling tells me this is a environment issue, rather than a code issue. There are two things that matters in this case - what's in the PATH variable and in JAVA_HOME. Might also be related to Maven.

Comment: Thank you..i am using "javac TransportationDriver.java" and I am inside the directory where all 3 files reside when attempt to compile. Not using Maven for this one. Just simple tutorial i was doing ..so much for simple..lol

Comment: You should really include a [mre] in your question, and that means you need to specify the exact layout of the files (where are they located), their exact content (e.g. is your code really in the default package, i.e. no `package` statement?), and the exact commands you use, and the exact output (e.g the error is not "Can't find symbol", it is "Cannot find symbol" and includes more text). Bar that information, the duplicate applies.

Comment: Thank you and sorry, I'm still learning. The package is the same for all 3 files (not the default). I added it to the codeblock in my post above now.

And you are correct the error is "Cannot find symbol". 

I will be more thorough next time.

Comment: `javac -d . *.java && java multFileCompile.TransportationDriver`

Comment: Thank you all for your help. As a test, i put all files in default and it complied fine. So that means there must be error in my naming convention for the package (I used some uppercase letters). Thank you

Comment: No, it won't be anything to do with naming style